# Stripe Checkout button style

Tags: css, stripe-payments

Using Stripe Checkout Server for payment, I'm struggling to have the "Pay" button with the nice/default Stripe style (white font, blue background, ...).

HTML code:

```
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<button id="payButton" class="stripe-button-el">Pay with credit card</button>

    <script>
        var stripe = Stripe('<?=STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY?>');
        var button = document.getElementById("payButton");
        button.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId:'<?=$session['id']?>'}).then(function(result) {});
                });
    </script>
```

I applied this the `stripe-button-el` class which turns the button to a blue background (so it is properly associated to a CSS file) but the font remains black. Screenshot:
[image]

How can I have the nice/default Stripe style applied to this button?

Many thx, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the css that styles the button or the button has not the required css classes so the style is not applied to it.
Where can we see how the button should look like? (in a HTML code)

Comment: I provided a screenshot of the button as it shows for now. I have the same hypothesis than you: I'm probably using the wrong class for the button or not linking a required css file. Unfortunately I couldn't find any doc on this

Answer (score 0):

This will change the color of the text

In your style sheet

```
 .stripe-button-el{color: white;}
```

Comment: Thx but I'm actually looking to have the standard stripe css applied, without manual edits